# Importing FSharp.Charting in .fs file fails

Tags: f#, fsharpchart

1. Create a new FSharp Console project via VS2015
2. Add FSharp.Data and FSharp.Charting nuget package.
3. In Program.fs import both the packages

`open FSharp.Charting
 open Fsharp.Data`

After the import I am able to use functions provided in FSharp.Data package but not in FSharp.Charting.

NOTE: In case of script (.fsx) file, which created in the same project, I am able to use both after adding their reference.

I just wanted to to know if there are any steps i am missing for adding any reference in a .fs file. If yes then why does it work with respect to FSharp.Data package.

Comment: Have you tried adding references to System.Drawing and possible to Winforms as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you search SO you'll find a few examples of displaying charts with FSharp.Charting. It's not exactly clear what sort of error are you getting. Assuming you are on Windows this should work:

```
open FSharp.Charting
open System

[<STAThread>]
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    Chart.Line [ for x in 0 .. 10 -> x, x*x ] |> Chart.Show
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

You will need to add references to `System.Windows.Forms`, `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization` and `System.Drawing`.

Comment: I had not added the System references... But in case of .fsx files I had not added those references and still the Charting functions were available.

Comment: @Parshuram Well, you never show how you actually reference FSharp.Charting. Two things to keep in mind, if you`re `#load`-ing FSLab or the FSharp.Charting fsx scripts it will do some set up for you. Also, FSI itself might open System and a couple of other namespaces (I haven't tested the latter).